# Python tkinter frame scrollbar: frame not expanding on the sides

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I am not sure where I am going wrong. The code should have the frames stretched out on the canvas so that we can be scrolling through each different frame one by one. Not sure where in the code I should change to have the frames inside the canvas expand their widths to cover across the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk

class sprintLog(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        self.happy1 = ""

    def sprintPage(self, framer):
        # Create A Canvas
        my_canvas = tk.Canvas(framer, bd=30, background="red", relief="sunken")
        my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(framer, orient="vertical", command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1,rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky="ns")
        my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky="nsew")
        framer.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        framer.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=90)
        #framer.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        
        #my_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # Configure The Canvas
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        xframe = tk.Frame(my_canvas, bd=10)
        

        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=xframe, anchor="center")
        
        projNavDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="yellow", relief="sunken", height=200)
        projTitle = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="blue", relief="sunken", height=200)
        discpProDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="red", relief="sunken", height=200)
        currSprintDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="green", relief="sunken", height=200)
        spriNaveDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="yellow", relief="sunken", height=200)
        sprintTableDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="red", relief="sunken", height=200)
        lastsecDiv = tk.Frame(xframe, bd=0, background="pink", relief="sunken", height=200)

        

        projNavDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        projTitle.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        discpProDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        currSprintDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        spriNaveDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        sprintTableDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")
        lastsecDiv.pack( side = "top", fill = "x")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700+150+30")
root.title("IT's PERSONAL: Project")

topContentFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="pink")
topContentFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xx = sprintLog()
xx.sprintPage(topContentFrame)
xx.mainloop()
```

Comment: The border on your xframe helps show some of issue. We can see the ```xframe``` windows has a small width (propbably 1) inside the ```canvas```. So the individual frames are behaving correclty, but the width of ```xframe``` needs to be defined or configured

Comment: ok, I thought the pack(), 'fill', would allow the xframe to inherit the canvas width. But that is ok, I'll just create a function that sets the size of the frames to get and fit the width according to the width of the canvas. Thanks!